# Как в regexp задать для поиска несколько слов?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Написал такой код:

```
var arr = ['ясно','понятно'];
var a = new RegExp(arr, 'i');
var b = 'ясно';
b.match(a);
```

К примеру в массиве arr 2 слова: 'ясно', 'понятно', и эти слова можно искать отдельно. Т.е. отдельно: 'ясно', отдельно: 'понятно'.

Как правильно задать для поиска несколько слов и как привести код в рабочее состояние?

Comment: `var a = new RegExp(arr.join('|'), 'i');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы хотите одним регулярным выражением искать два слова "ясно" и "понятно" можно воспользоваться символом | позволяющего реализовать в регулярных выражениях логику ИЛИ

```
var a = new RegExp('ясно|понятно', 'i');
```

с использованием массива из вашего примера сформировать регулярное выражение можно, задействовав метод `join()`

```
var arr = ['ясно','понятно'];
var a = new RegExp(arr.join('|'), 'i');
```